# code page for GB18030 MSDN(C++)

Tags: c++

Does Chinese Code page .936, covers 4 Byte chinese characters in MSDN(C++)?

Currently for 2 byte Chinese data, 'chs' is used as a locale name.

Could anyone let me know, what would be the locale name for GB18030 if available as seperate in MSDN. i tried passing 54936 with reference from MSDN, but failed to achieve it.

Awaiting for your valuable response.

Thanks in Advance Guyz

Comment: Using "Unicode" (UTF-16) is generally a lot easier in Win32.

Answer (score 0):

No: ["A multibyte character set may consist of both one-byte and two-byte characters. "](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bb3e64h.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no locale name found for 'GB18030'.

Only 'chs' is available and its used for Chinese language.

Regards,
Ganesh Sha